# Why ^^! and not ^! for literal escapes during delayed variable expansion?

Tags: batch-file, escaping, delayedvariableexpansion

When delayed variable expansion is enabled, why do we require two escape characters for literal exclamation marks? `^^!` vs `^!`

I checked a lot of forums, and there's no explanation for it.

Answer (score 4):

Referring to the thread [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699), the reason for this is that there are two phases that support `^`-escaping:

- **Phase 2**, special character recognition and tokenisation: an unquoted escape character `^` needs to be escaped as `^^` in order for a literal one to be passed over to further phases.
- **Phase 5**, delayed expansion:

  - if enabled, a caret `^` that reaches this point can be used to escape special characters, while there are only two such at this point, namely the exclamation mark `!` and the caret `^`;
  - if disabled, the exclamation mark as well as the caret have no special meaning whatsoever;

So, this results in the following behaviour:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo ^^!   exclamation mark (proper escaping)
echo ^!    lost exclamation mark (insufficient escaping, unpaired)
echo !    lost exclamation mark (unpaired)
echo "^!" quoted exclamation mark
echo "!"  lost quoted exclamation mark (unpaired)
endlocal
echo/
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
echo ^^!  exclamation mark (exaggerated escaping)
echo ^!   exclamation mark (superfluous escaping)
echo !   exclamation mark (unescaped)
echo "^!" quoted exclamation mark (exaggerated escaping)
echo "!"  lost quoted exclamation mark (unescaped)
endlocal
exit /B
```

Here is the resulting output:

> ```cmd
> !   exclamation mark (proper escaping)
>     lost exclamation mark (insufficient escaping, unpaired)
>     lost exclamation mark (unpaired)
> "!" quoted exclamation mark
> ""  lost quoted exclamation mark (unpaired)
>
> ^!  exclamation mark (exaggerated escaping)
> !   exclamation mark (superfluous escaping)
> !   exclamation mark (unescaped)
> "^!" quoted exclamation mark (exaggerated escaping)
> "!"  lost quoted exclamation mark (unescaped)
> ```